# windows git bash wont clone directory

Tags: git, github, git-clone, git-bash

I am having trouble cloning a git repo using git bash.

Basically im trying to do the following from the angular js tutorial [angular js tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

```
#Clone the angular-phonecat repository located at Github by running the following command:
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

However when I do it it seems to hang and fail on the cloning into angular-phonecar dir.  See screenshot.  The url is avtive and I can open it when I load it into my browser?  So im thinking I may have the ports blocked?...  not sure..

Any help would be much appreciated.  Error says http request failed

[image: screenshot of fail]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either GitHub was down, or maybe you are behind a firewall that is blocking access to this. Have you tried connecting to GitHub using curl?

```
curl -I https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

Also, after the clone operation fails, enter this in the command line:

```
echo $?
```

That is the exit code of the last command. You might try googling "git clone fails with exit code X".